# Random Quote Selector Not Repating Quotes After Each Other

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to create a random quote selector in Javascript that does not repeat the same quote twice after each other. My problem is not being able to figure out how not to let the quotes to be repeated.

Javascript:

```
function start() {
  var quotes = [];

  quotes.push({"content": "Quote #1", "cite": "—Cite #1"});
  quotes.push({"content": "Quote #2", "cite": "—Cite #2"});
  quotes.push({"content": "Quote #3”, "cite": "—Cite #3"});
  quotes.push({"content": "Quote #4", "cite": "—Cite #4"});
  quotes.push({"content": "Quote #5", "cite": "—Cite #5"});

  var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * quotes.length);

  $('#containerQuotes blockquote').text(quotes[randomNumber]['content'])
   .fadeIn(2000)
   .delay(2000)
   .fadeOut(2000, start);
  $('#containerQuotes cite').text(quotes[randomNumber]['cite'])
   .fadeIn(2000)
   .delay(2000)
   .fadeOut(2000, start);
} start();
```

HTML:

```
<div id="containerQuotes">
  <div class="fa fa-quote-left fa-2x"></div>
    <blockquote>Default Quote</blockquote><cite>Default Cite</cite>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#containerQuotes {
  bottom: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  left: 0px;
  margin-left: 600px;
  margin-right: 600px;
  position: absolute;
}
```

Anybody got any suggestions? If someone knows another way of implementing this, I'm all ears.

Thank you,
drujd3ka

(the CSS formatting has some quirks for now, but I want to work this one out first)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remove the item from the array once it's picked:

```js
const quotes = [
  {"content": "Quote #1", "cite": "—Cite #1"},
  {"content": "Quote #2", "cite": "—Cite #2"},
  {"content": "Quote #3", "cite": "—Cite #3"},
  {"content": "Quote #4", "cite": "—Cite #4"},
  {"content": "Quote #5", "cite": "—Cite #5"},
];
function start() {
  var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * quotes.length);
  $('#containerQuotes blockquote').text(quotes[randomNumber]['content'])
   .fadeIn(2000)
   .delay(2000)
   .fadeOut(2000);
  $('#containerQuotes cite').text(quotes[randomNumber]['cite'])
   .fadeIn(2000)
   .delay(2000)
   .fadeOut(2000, start);
  quotes.splice(randomNumber, 1);
}
start();
```

```css
#containerQuotes {
  bottom: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  left: 0px;
  margin-left: 600px;
  margin-right: 600px;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="containerQuotes">
  <div class="fa fa-quote-left fa-2x"></div>
    <blockquote>Default Quote</blockquote><cite>Default Cite</cite>
</div>
```

Note that you need to use straight quotes rather than so-called "smart quotes", else you'll get a syntax error.

Also, only pass in `start` to *one* of the `fadeOut`s, otherwise additional `start`s will start running each subsequent iteration.